# I have no boot options in the firmware's SETUP utility at all and so cannot boot anything

Tags: boot, bios, uefi

The "Boot" page of the Aptio SETUP program in my PC's firmware looks like this:

[image: screenshot of Aptio SETUP, boot page]

I don't have any boot options, so my machine doesn't boot!

Here's what I *think* that it should look like (although this is a slightly later version of SETUP) from someone else's computer that I found on the World Wide Web:

[image: screenshot of Aptio SETUP, boot page]

In the other person's screenshot, there's a boot option for Windows Boot Manager.  There's also a menu entry for adding more boot options.  I have neither.  We both have CSM and fast boot disabled, though.

I've found a second person with CSM *en*abled, and xe has more boot options and more menu entries:

[image: screenshot of Aptio SETUP, boot page]

What do I do to make my machine boot, and have all of these boot options that other people's machines have?

Comment: Why can't you edit boot options?

Comment: But what are you trying to do? What is your problem?

Comment: Am I the only person to have _looked at the screenshot_?  It's actually fairly clear what the questioner is asking, from that.  Here you go.

Answer (score 3):

The firmware boot options are normally added by an OS during installation. If an OS is already installed, OS-specific tools like Linux's `efibootmgr` or Windows' `bcdedit` can add options. So can the EFI shell's `bcfg` command. [This page of mine](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/installation.html) covers the process in more detail for Linux. If you care to provide more details about your specific needs (OS(es) currently installed, OS(es) you want to install, etc.), a more detailed answer might be possible.

Comment: In my case the EFI system was broken until I upgraded the BIOS, the boot option tools crashed. After BIOS upgrade and Ubuntu clean install, everything works out of the box.